# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, ios7, nsurl

I am scratching my head as to what is happening here.....The print plugin is not working...
I am trying to add a printer plugin to an application..after mapping up my xml and loading  html file, I do not see an error in Xcode. 
However, as I run the application it crashes and the log states :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

I am worried as I am unable to overcome it since the last 24 hours...Any help will be great..or if someone can let me know of how to exactly get a printer plugin working in my app will be good....The code I am using is

```
// Set the base URL to be the www directory.
NSString* wwwFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www" ofType:nil];
NSURL*    baseURL     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wwwFilePath];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to post so much code. Just post relevant code which are the following two lines:

```
NSString* wwwFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www" ofType:nil];
NSURL*    baseURL     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wwwFilePath];
```

The problems is that `wwwFilePath` is `nil` which means that you do not have a file named `www` in your app bundle.

Either add the missing file or update the name of the file in the call to `pathForResource:ofType:` with the proper filename.

BTW - the two lines can simply be:

```
NSURL *basEURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"www" withExtension:nil];
```

but again you still need to pass in a valid filename/extension.

Comment: When I add a valid filename/extension to the method, the error I get is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...I am lost...help

Comment: You should close out this question by accepted the best answer and post your new issue as a new question. Remember to post relevant code and fully explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is in your error log `reason: '* -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil`, You cann't pass `nil` parameter to `initFileURLWithPath:`. Just check and call this method as below.

```
NSString* wwwFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www" ofType:nil];
if( wwwFilePath)
   NSURL*    baseURL     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wwwFilePath];
```

Comment: When I add a valid filename/extension to the method, the error I get is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...I am lost...help

Comment: This error is in some other line. You've to check with your response, Because you may receive null response but you try to do encoding operation with NSNull. Check with your code.

Answer (score 0):

By the commend in your source code, you're stating that `www` is a directory.

```
// Set the base URL to be the www directory.
NSString* wwwFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www" ofType:nil];
```

I don't think `pathForResource` will consider a directory a valid resource. Remember that a resource is a file, and this method will try to search in the given bundle for a resource with that name.

Comment: When I add a valid filename/extension to the method, the error I get is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...I am lost...help

Comment: You need to check in every step of your routine if the objects you're being returned are null, this will help you to identify the offending line.