# *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter" in AppDelegate.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
   override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: 
    Any]?
) -> Bool {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
   return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
   launchOptions)
  }
}
```

This is my AppDelegate.Swift file.
When I am running my FLUTTER APP, it launches, and then it terminates the app with the exception:

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

I'm scratching my head for hours to solve this.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551038/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-nsurl-initfileurlwithpath-nil-st

Comment: The code you have posted is not where the crash occurred

Comment: You gave the error in console, that's great. But could you also give what's before or after with the stacktrace?

Comment: Stack trace would be the very first thing to check. And set a breakpoint for Objective-C exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Check assets folder.
Names of your assets files doesn't match to origin ones. Some plugins just doesn't handle it.